# MacVim: Pydiction unable to use

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to add Pydiction into MacVim, I followed the readme file.

Put python_pydiction.vim in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ and write:

```
let g:pydiction_location = '~/pydiction/complete-dict'
```

into my .vimrc file. But when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> in MacVim, an error will rise:

```
undefined variable g:pydiction_location
```

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong ?

Comment: maybe a silly question, but did you try restarting VIM after all this?

Comment: Yes, I tried. By the way I have pathogen, does that matter?

Comment: In VIM if you type :echo g:pydiction_location what is the output? If it's undefined, try :source ~/.vimrc next

Comment: I tried :echo g:pydiction_location and get E121: Undefined variable E15: Invalid expression: g:pydiction_location

Comment: that means it's not being set. Make sure you are adding it to your ~/.vimrc file. Do :e $MYVIMRC in vim and make sure it's in that file.

Comment: That works! Thank you! I somehow messed up with two vimrc files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you were editing a file that wasn't actually your .vimrc file. You may have typed:

```
:e vimrc
:e ~/vimrc
:e .vimrc
```

none of which will probably edit your actual .vimrc file. It must have a dot in front of it AND be located in your home directory. You can also type `:pwd` in vim to see the current working directory. If you do `:e .vimrc` it will create a new file in whatever directory you are in if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use NERDTree? If so it seems that Pydiction and NERDTree conflict with each other in some way.